# Jenkins DSL Jobs: GroovyCastException Cannot cast object

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I am new to groovy and to Jenkins DSL jobs. I am trying to use a groovy script to create jobs that run test scripts. I am running into a Cannot cast object error and am not sure what the issue is and where the casting is getting thrown off. The error message doesnt seem to point to a specific line, bit I thought it might be an issue with the class not importing, but it seems like it is. It seems like the error has to do with the JenkinsDSL file.

Below is are the two files that I created and the error message. The JenkinsDSL.groovy contains a method that takes in parameters to create the job.

Thank you in advance!

**Update**
I ran it through this website: http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ and it confirms that the issue is in JenkinsDSL.groovy

**JenkinsDSL.groovy**

```
class JenkinsDSL {
    String gitUrl, gitRemoteName, gitBranch, gitCredentials
    String project, testSuite, testCaseName, testCaseDesc

    def addJob(def dslFactory, String project, String testSuite, String testCaseName, String testCaseDesc) {

        dslFactory.folder("Selenium Tests") {
            displayName("Selenium Tests")
            description("someDescription")
        }

        dslFactory.listView(project) {
           description("Tests for ${project}")
            filterBuildQueue()
            filterExecutors()
            jobs { 
            }
            columns {
                status()
                weather()
                name()
                lastSuccess()
                lastFailure()
                lastDuration()
                buildButton()
            }
        }

        dslFactory.folder(testSuite) {
            displayName(testSuite)
            description("Verifies functionality related to ${testSuite}")
        }

        dslFactory.mavenJob("Selenium Tests/${project}/${testSuite}/${testCaseName}") {
            description("${testCaseDesc}")
            label('AWS-Linux-Java-7')
            wrappers {
                timeout {
                    absolute(5)
                }
            }
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        name("${gitRemoteName}")
                        url("${gitUrl}")
                        credentials("${gitCredentials}")
                    }
                    branch("${gitBranch}")
                }
            }
            parameters {
                choiceParam('Browser', ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari'])
                choiceParam('Environment', ['Dev', 'Test'])
                choiceParam('TestCase', ["${testCaseName}"])
            }
            triggers {
                parameterizedCron('''
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Dev;TestCase=TestCase
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Dev;TestCase=TestCase
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Dev;TestCase=TestCase
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Chrome;Environment=Test;TestCase=TestCase
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Firefox;Environment=Test;TestCase=TestCase
                    H 0 * * * % Browser=Safari;Environment=Test;TestCase=TestCase
                ''')
            }

            rootPOM("pom.xml")
            goals("clean test -DBrowser='$BROWSER' -DEnvironment='$ENVIRONMENT' -DTestCase='$TESTCASE'");

            publishers {
                archiveArtifacts {
                    pattern('target/surefire-reports/customized-emailable-report.html')
                    pattern('target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html')
                    pattern('target/surefire-reports/index.html')
                    pattern('target/surefire-reports/screenshots/**')
                }
                wsCleanup {
                includePattern('target/surefire-reports/**')
                deleteDirectories(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**PortalDSL.groovy**

```
import JenkinsDSL;

def job = new JenkinsDSL(
    gitUrl: 'giturl',
    gitRemoteName: 'gitname',
    gitBranch: 'gitbranch',
    gitCredentials: 'gitcreds'
)

/********************************** Project 1 **********************************/

/***************** Test Suite 1 *****************/

/*** Test Case 1 ***/
job.addJob(
    this,
    'projectName',
    'testSuite',
    'testCase1',
    'Some Description'
)
/*** Test Case 2 ***/
job.addJob(
     this,
    'projectName',
    'testSuite',
    'testCase2',
    'Some Description'
)
```

**Jenkins Error Message**

```
Processing DSL script JenkinsDSL.groovy
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1@620c0d02' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1' to class 'javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent'
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScriptEngine(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:103)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader$_runScripts_closure1.doCall(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2078)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$164.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.AbstractDslScriptLoader.runScripts(AbstractDslScriptLoader.groovy:46)
at javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.ExecuteDslScripts.perform(ExecuteDslScripts.java:323)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Cannot cast object 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1@620c0d02' with class 'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$1' to class 'javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.JobParent'
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Jenkins Job DSL and Jenkins Pipeline in your code. Read up on Job DSL here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I have made edits to try to get rid of the Pipeline in my code, but I am still getting a similar error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it mightve been due to my configuration in Jenkins. In the Process Job DSLs" -> Look on Filesystem -> DSL Scripts, I had put "*.groovy". Instead, I should have put "PortalDSL.groovy"

ellak pointed out that I had Jenkins Pipeline in my code as well, but I have updated the code to not include the Pipeline syntax.